# What means non-commercial and commecial use of software? (Question with examples)

Tags: software

Have a laptop with OS GNU Linux with many kinda of software: browsers, text tools, players, system tools, IDE's. I use it in home no for working: for reading news  watching YouTube, learning, creating personal opensource project.

And I use this laptop on the work in office: solve tasks from the boss in IDE, try to find help with solving in Internet (browsers), create documents with text tools, watch video from work. One per month for this I got money.

I cannot understand one moment. Is my usage commercial or non-commercial for? For:

1. OS GNU Linux
2. Browsers
3. Text tools
4. IDE's
5. Players

Answer (score -1):

If you use software both for personal use and commercial use, the times where you used it commercially count as commercial use. Some commercial-use licenses indirectly restrict you from using the software for personal use as well (e.g., site licenses may be restricted to company use).  However, software that is licensed for commercial use by seat (computer or person) often do not have such restrictions.

If your employer has paid for software/hardware, I recommend against using it for personal use without their permission.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question

Comment: @JBentley: Could you go into more detail? What is missing from this answer for it to be considered an answer?

Comment: The question gives examples of usage and asks whether that usage is commercial or non commercial. You didn't answer that question. A basic answer would say for example "watching the news on YouTube is non commercial", "solving tasks for the boss is commercial" (or whatever you think the case is) etc. A better answer would explain the difference between commercial and non commercial uses. An even better answer would give legal citations if any exist.